# BigQuery - set "" as Null

Tags: google-bigquery

I get csv files where string null value expressed as `""`,
when I load the file to `BigQuery` the value of the field is empty string
and not `Null`.

Is there a way to set BigQuery to see `""` as `Null` value?

Answer (score 19):

Adding this for those who might still need it. There is a `NULLIF` function that can do this easily.

```
NULLIF(column_name,'')
```

What this does is if `column_name` is an empty string i.e. `''`, it puts `NULL`, if not, it puts the `column_name` value.

Comment: I wish I had know about this nullif() a couple of years back! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that it might be easiest to simply remove all instances of `""` from the original file. (Through find and replace.)

Otherwise, once you have loaded the table into BigQuery, you could select all columns, apply `case when column_name = '' then null else column_name end` to the relevant column, and save the results as a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the command line tool that comes with the Google Cloud SDK (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads)?  If so, check out `bq help load` to see the parameters on the `load` command.  One of the flags that you can pass is `--null_marker`.

I haven't verified whether or not this flag supports the empty string, but if Google Cloud supported it, it would be there.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `--null_marker` to recognize the empty string. I tried passing `""` and `'""'`.